# Rust CXX crate defaults to MSVCRT DynamicRelease

Tags: c++, rust-cargo, msvcrt

i'm trying to integrate a rust crate as a staticlib to our legacy Visual C++ project. I have used CXX crate for interop with no c++ side code on the bridge.

I was able to build a static runtime when i set `rustflags = ["-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static"]` in my .cargo/config.toml. But how do i get a Debug version? My visual c++ project has a MSVCRT /MTd_StaticDebug, how do i set this on my cargo project.

Note: linking with target/debug build does not solve. I was able to link my rust staticlib to a cpp project successfully in visual studio code using clang++.